# Why does this throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception

I've been working on a GUI, but have found a problem. About 10% of the time I launch the program, I get a ClassCastException, but the code doesn't hang and isn't executed strangely. It just runs like normal. What's weirder is the stack trace never references any code I've written. I tried to confirm this by wrapping everything in a try-catch, and sure enough, the error is still thrown and never caught. Since it never really affects the code, I guess it's not causing any harm, but I'd still much rather not release code that has a bug I don't understand in it.

Here is the code as simplified as I can get it to still repeat the error:

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ErrorTracker extends JFrame{

    private JButton addRow;
    private JScrollPane pane;
    private JPanel scrollPanel, panel;
    private JFrame frame; 

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        /**
         * The error only occurs sometimes, so I'm running it 20 times to
         * make the odds of repeating the error pretty good.
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            new ErrorTracker();
    }

    public ErrorTracker() {
        /**
         * Proof that the error somehow occurs outside of all the code... 
         * The line "An error took place" is never outputted. 
         **/
        try {
            initialize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error took place");
        }
    }

    public void initialize () {
        frame = new JFrame("Apparently this is defective");

        JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        frame.add(bigPanel);

        addRow = new JButton("...");

        scrollPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPanel.add(addRow);

        pane = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel);
        bigPanel.add(pane);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(addRow);
    }
}
```

I know with 99% certainty that adding `addRow` twice is at least some of the reason for this, since taking out either of the `add(addRow)` lines removes the problem. Before anyone suggests changing that, don't worry. I will. However, this question is mainly geared towards understanding why this error is occurring. Getting rid of `frame.setVisible(true);` removes the problem as well, so I imagine when the GUI is being drawn, it's done so in it's own Thread which is really angry about adding the same element to two `JPanel`s (that would explain why my code isn't in the stack trace, I think...), but I don't understand that process well enough to know for sure.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy.getInitialComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.getMostRecentFocusOwner(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know why this error is being thrown? Am I right about this being in another thread, and if not, why doesn't the stack trace ever reference my code? Also, why does it only throw the error some of the time?

Comment: Your class extends `JFrame`. There is no need for the private member `frame`.

Comment: Is it this bug? http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013775

Comment: @khelwood I think it is that bug!! Does that mean this is happening because adding `addRow` to a `JPanel` after I make `addRow` visible messes with components in my main thread that the Swing thread is using? I'll go ahead and click the "that solved my problem" for this duplicate, but I'd love to make sure I fully grasp this first

Comment: `it's done so in it's own Thread which is really angry` Recommend always calling Swing method from the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) - wrap your Swing calls on other Threads using `SwingUtilities.invoke*`

Answer (score 0):

First you guess right, the issue is because you add addRow two times. By chance the panel where you add the second time is not show in the frame.
A component in Swing MUST have only one parent, it can't be give to two parent in same time. If you want change the parent of a component, you have to remove it first from it's parent the add it to other one, and invalidate the both parents to see to result.

The class cast exception happen because internally the parent is confuse